# Кроссбраузерность блока

Tags: css3, html5, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Сверстал сайт по макету. Нужным элементам добавил вендорные префиксы. Однако есть участки на сайте, которые работают во всех браузерах прекрасно, но именно в IE, вёрстка по ним "плывёт". Не могу разобраться, что делаю не так. В примере ниже две фотографии сильно искажены, при отображении в IE, в остальных браузерах отображаются нормально, в круглом блоке с border-radius: 50%;

Привожу пример:

```css
.offer_info {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.offer_info,
.info_1,
.info_2 {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info_1 {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.info_2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.img_1,
.img_2 {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.style_img {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1db05e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.offer .text_info {
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #566375;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer_info">

  <div class="info_1">

    <div class="img_1">
      <div class="style_img">
        <img src="img/fon_info1.png" alt="img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text_info">
      Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi gravida tellus in purus pharetra, vel dignissim mauris viverra. Maecenas vitae risus est. In hendrerit, massa at.
    </p>

  </div>

  <div class="info_2">

    <div class="img_2">
      <div class="style_img">
        <img src="img/fon_info2.png" alt="img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text_info">
      Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi gravida tellus in purus pharetra, vel dignissim mauris viverra. Maecenas vitae risus est. In hendrerit, massa at.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: IE используют меньше 1.5% народу, для чего он вам?

Comment: @andreymal и эта "львиная" доля людей сидят на нём только потому, что компании заставляют подчинённых сидеть в этом доисторическом браузере.

Comment: Дело в том, что я изучаю вёрстку, с целью устроиться на работу верстальщиком. А если заказчик даст мне такое задание в реальной практике, и потребует полной кроссбраузерности? Я ведь должен буду справиться. Честно, не пойму что не так в коде, добавил normalize.css, везде добавил префиксы, но есть много коротких моментов в сайте, где вёрстка плывёт именно в IE. Как исправить, не знаю....

Comment: У IE крайне хреновая поддержка флексов, поэтому проблема скорее всего в IE и его криворуких разработчиках. Но если вам хочется, чтобы была обозначена проблема в вашем коде, то тогда проблема в том, что вы используете флексы :)

Comment: Забейте на IE. Когда дадут такую задачу, тогда и будете думать над конкретной проблемой. Они всегда разные, и то что вы решите что-то сейчас, вас не спасёт от проблем в IE в будущем, потому что там проблем сотни. И чем далее во времени, тем всё меньше вероятность, что IE будет нужен. Многие уже давно его выкинули из поддержки и стараются отговорить заказчиков от него, потому что ради 1-3 процента клиентов обычно не стОит тратить кучу времени и ухудшать-усложнять код для всех остальных клиентов.

Comment: Благодарю за рекомендации. Вы меня успокоили, я уже немного духом упал, думал что крайне не квалифицированный. Кроме IE, мой сайт все браузеры поддержали, значит не всё уж тк и плохо у меня вышло) Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Вот сайт который я делал -  https://krutov69.github.io/portfolio_4/    Буду признателен, если немного прокомментируете недостатки, как новичку мне будет очень полезно.